How do I make apps in Dash to Panel have rounded edges and how do I remove the double effect?
How do I make the running-app/mouse-over app highlight boxes have rounded edges and remove the running-app/mouse-over double effect in the Dash To Panel extension?
I had this question for about 6 months in Ubuntu, it is just an aesthetic detail, and now I reinstalled Ubuntu (in this case Ubuntu 24.04) there is a double effect when a app is running or when I put the mouse on it. See the following screenshot:


Welcome to AskUbuntu. Did you try disabling the extension and check the double effect??
